Can't Import NAD83 / NRCan LCC Canada (EPSG:42304) in QGIS
I need to define the NAD83 / NRCan LCC Canada (EPSG:42304) CRS in QGIS to use the NBAC wildfire data from https://cwfis.cfs.nrcan.gc.ca/datamart/metadata/nbac.
Since QGIS does not recognize this CRS I attempted to add a custom CRS in QGIS... Settings->Options->User Defined CRS... but it won't accept the WKT copied from (https://epsg.io/42304).
QGIS returns the error:

The Definition is not Valid.

I also tried using the PROJ.4, but QGIS returns that those values are the same as EPSG::3978 and it won't add them.
I am using QGIS 3.28 on an Ubuntu box.

Away from my QGIS box, but suggest trying a) making sure you Copy Text rather than just Cut'n'Paste (or Copy formatted) from epsg.io, and b) try OGC WKT 2 and ESRI WKT formats as well as the default OGC WKT 1. QGIS/proj should accept any one of the 3, but when stuck worth trying....

Use EPSG:3978 https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2011-June/069307.html
